# Returning mySQL error with jQuery & AJAX

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax

I've got a form inserting data into mySQL. It works but I'm trying to add error handling in case something happens. If I break the Insert statements mySQL dies but I'm still getting a success message on the front end. What am I doing wrong?

AJAX

```
  function postData(){
  var employeeName = jQuery('#employeeName').val();
  var hireDate = jQuery('#hireDate').val();
  var position = jQuery('#position').val();
  var location = jQuery('#location').val();
  var interveiwer = jQuery('#interviewersID').val();
  var q01 = jQuery('#q01').val();
  var q02 = jQuery('#q02').val();
  var q03 = jQuery('#q03').val();
  var q04 = jQuery('#q04').val();
  var q05 = jQuery('#q05').val();
  var summary = jQuery('#summary').val();

  jQuery.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'queryDay.php',
      data: 'employeeName='+ employeeName +'&hireDate='+ hireDate +'&position='+ position +'&location='+ location +'&interveiwer='+ interveiwer +'&q01='+ q01 +'&q02='+ q02 +'&q03='+ q03 +'&q04='+ q04 +'&q05='+ q05 +'&summary='+ summary,
      success: function(){
          jQuery('#formSubmitted').show();
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
          jQuery('#returnError').html(errorThrown);
          jQuery('#formError').show();
      }
  });
};
```

PHP

```
require_once 'config.php';

$employeeName = $_POST['employeeName'];
$hireDate = $_POST['hireDate'];
$position = $_POST['position'];
$location = $_POST['location'];
$interviewerID = $_POST['interveiwer'];
$q01 = $_POST['q01'];
$q02 = $_POST['q02'];
$q03 = $_POST['q03'];
$q04 = $_POST['q04'];
$q05 = $_POST['q05'];
$summary = $_POST['summary'];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO employee (name, hiredate, position, location) VALUES ('$employeeName', '$hireDate', '$position', '$location')") or die (mysql_error());

$employeeID = mysql_insert_id();

mysql_query("INSERT INTO day (employee, interviewer, datetaken, q01, q02, q03, q04, q05, summary) VALUES ('$employeeID', '$interviewerID', NOW(), '$q01', '$q02', '$q03', '$q04', '$q05', '$summary')") or die (mysql_error());
```

Comment: As an aside, you should use [PDO](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead, as the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.  I also hope this site is not live, as as it stands, your code is vulnerable to injection attacks.

Comment: Just wondering...why not use `$('#some_id').foo()` instead of `jQuery('#some_id'.foo()`?

Comment: @ecbrodie I don't see anywhere that they do that.

Comment: @Daedalus Thanks for the heads up on PDO, nothing is live, I know there are security issues that need to be addressed.

Comment: @ecbrodie are you talking about using jQuery instead of $? I've always done that to avoid issues when I'm working in Joomla or WordPress.

Comment: He may be using prototype in which case jQuery is okay, but something shorter is probably advisable.

Answer (score 1):

### The issue is with your head(ers)

The mysql error page is returning a 200 okay header. You will need to change this to an error header and jquery will pick it up as an error, else it will think it is a success.

Or on the other hand you could catch the mysql error and return some text that you then catch and read client side, but this will be caught within the success handler.